# Preventing default-compiler to run in Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-compiler-plugin

I am trying to write a compiler plugin for maven:

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>my-custom-compiler</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                            <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                            <compilerArgument>-Xdiags:verbose</compilerArgument>
                            <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                            <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>${project.basedir}\src\main\java\testfiles\</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Now when i run mvn clean install I see that the:

> [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile)

default compiler still being executed. Does is always happen like this? Or is there a way to stop its execution. It isn't harming anything. But compiling the same 2000 odd files is slowing the build down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add your configuration to the default-compile like:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                        <compilerArgument>-Xdiags:verbose</compilerArgument>
                        <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>${project.basedir}\src\main\java\testfiles\</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Then `clean install` will just run your configuration.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am doing right now, but I just wanted to know if the "default" one could be prevented in any way.

Comment: But why avoid it instead of just override it? You can try to use `<skipMain>` for that, but I do not understand why you write your own call of compile and deactivate the original one instead of just overriding the original one.

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot about this. I modified the default one and went ahead as you asked. The only reason i was asking was to find out if there was a way of doing it or not. Thanks for the help!!!